# SCOM - with powershell, from a list of specific machines, check if each is monitored

Tags: powershell, scom

I don't know a lot about SCOM, but i'm trying to understand (please explain in laymens terms) what the difference is between these 4 powershell commands:

```
Get-SCOMGroup -DisplayName "All Windows Computers" | Get-SCOMClassInstance

Get-SCOMClass -DisplayName "Windows Computer" | Get-SCOMClassInstance

Get-SCOMagent

Get-SCOMMonitoringObject -class (Get-SCOMClass -Name "Microsoft.SystemCenter.Agent")
```

My objective is to determine if a list of computers appear in the SCOM console and are considered "monitored".. going through the fat client GUI is incredibly slow and cumbersome and doesn't encapsulate if a machine is just "pending" management and needs approval or is "agentless" managed (whatever that means) so an all encompassing powershell script is preferred.

Which (if any) of the above commands is the right way to go? Surely somebody has had to do this before so i hope someone can just quote me a finished script that ive (thus far) failed to find with google.. any help most appreciated!